# Kentico sitemap not rendering with XML extension

Tags: kentico

I've gone through the documentation, set a page with the correct webpart, checked the web.config, and my sitemap only renders out the XML with .aspx.

here's my web.config snippet. I did make any changes here.

```html
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
      <remove name="XHtmlModule" />
      <remove name="CMSApplicationModule" />
      <add name="XHtmlModule" type="CMS.OutputFilter.OutputFilterModule, CMS.OutputFilter" />
      <add name="CMSApplicationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="CMS.Base.ApplicationModule, CMS.Base" />  
    
    
    </modules>
```

I even tried an alias on the portal page.

Answer (score 0):

In your settings you can set this.  Go to Settings>URLs and SEO>Search engine optimization (SEO) and the first 2 boxes are what you want to set.  The first box (Google sitemap URL) is the actual URL you'll navigate to.  The second box (Google sitemap path) is where in the content tree the Google sitemap URL will get the content from.

So to say it a different way, the path is the holder of the actual sitemap content.  While the URL is where you will actually navigate to to get the sitemap.

For instance if you have `sitemap.xml` in the Google sitemap path and your actual sitemap is located in the content tree at `/special-pages/google-site-map` you'd never navigate to the `/special-pages/google-site-map` page, only the `/sitemap.xml` page and that is what you'd submit to the search engines as well.

Comment: the sitemap template is in the content tree root, and left the SEO settings at default. What's odd is sitemap.aspx gives me the expected XML, sitemap.xml doesn't give a 404 error, just a blank page. I thought the web.config adjustment meant .xml would work as an extension.

Comment: Go through the settings as I mentioned.  Leaving them at default won't work.  You need to have your Google sitemap path set to /sitemap.aspx to render properly when you navigate to googlesitemap.xml.

Comment: It's working now. I just got my local dev licenses, so i'm hoping that will clear up some issues i've been having.